# How to set up QSpinbox increment bigger than +1?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt-creator, qspinbox

In different areas of program i need to set different increment somewhere by +1 and somewehere by +2 or more. How to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `setSingleStep()` method:

> This property holds the step value.
>
> When the user uses the arrows to change the spin box's value the value
>   will be incremented/decremented by the amount of the singleStep. The
>   default value is 1. Setting a singleStep value of less than 0 does
>   nothing.

```
spinBox->setSingleStep(2);
```

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qspinbox.html#singleStep-prop

Answer (score 2):

Another method:

If you create the `spinBox` using design mode, then click the `spinBox` of your choice and change the value of property called `singleStep`. By default it is 1, but you can change it to 2 or any other number (step size will be changed to that number).